# Swift tests fail with "module map file" error from time to time

Tags: swift, server, ubuntu-16.04

I am developing with Swift 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 (under a Docker container). I run a series of Swift tests (using `swift test` ...) at the command line, using a script. An example command line is:

```
swift test -Xswiftc -DDEBUG -Xswiftc -DSERVER -Xswiftc -DPRIMARY_OWNING_GOOGLE1 --filter ServerTests.UserControllerTests
```

For completeness sake, here is the script I'm using to run my tests:
https://github.com/crspybits/SyncServerII/blob/master/Tools/runTests.sh

Between tests, my script uses `swift package clean` to clean up build products. However, seemingly randomly I sometimes get test failures with output like this:

```
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/root/Apps/SyncServerII/SyncServerII/.build/checkouts/CCurl.git--3354261816655650653/module.modulemap' not found <unknown>:0: error: module map file 
'/root/Apps/SyncServerII/SyncServerII/.build/checkouts/CCurl.git--3354261816655650653/module.modulemap' not found <unknown>:0: error: module map file 
'/root/Apps/SyncServerII/SyncServerII/.build/checkouts/CCurl.git--3354261816655650653/module.modulemap' not found <unknown>:0: error: module map file 
'/root/Apps/SyncServerII/SyncServerII/.build/checkouts/CCurl.git--3354261816655650653/module.modulemap' not found
```

or like this:

```
<module-includes>:1:10: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#include "/root/Apps/SyncServerII/SyncServerII/.build/checkouts/Kitura-net.git-7914159224218470268/Sources/CHTTPParser/include/CHTTPParser.h"
         ^ /root/Apps/SyncServerII/SyncServerII/.build/checkouts/Kitura-net.git-7914159224218470268/Sources/CHTTPParser/include/CHTTPParser.h:21:10: error: 'utils.h' file not found
#include "utils.h"
         ^ /root/Apps/SyncServerII/SyncServerII/.build/checkouts/Kitura-net.git-7914159224218470268/Sources/KituraNet/HTTPParser/HTTPParser.swift:17:8: error: could not build C module 'CHTTPParser' import CHTTPParser
       ^
```

Note that this is *not* a problem with the execution of my test, but rather a problem that occurs when the Swift tools are building the code in preparation to run my test.

I could just delete the entire build products directory (.build) between `swift test` invocations but that would increase my testing times greatly. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Nothing explicit. It does seem to be happening less often (not at all?) given that I've switched over to using `Swift version 4.1.2 (swift-4.1.2-RELEASE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be not be exactly related to the above, but just in case you are using CocoaPods and you get missing "module map file" error for any pod dependency, try to update to a newer CocoaPods version. Check your version first with `pods --version` and then `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

Comment: In my case, this was *not* a CocoaPods issue. This is "pure" Swift in my case separate from Xcode and iOS apps. Running under Linux. Please see my original question (Docker, Ubuntu).